# view from recursive query error

Tags: sql-server, view, syntax-error, common-table-expression

I have a recursive query that works just fine:

```
with cte as (
         select ps.SetProduct from PRODSET ps
         left join PRODUCT pr on pr.Product= ps.Product
         where ...

         union all

         select ps.SetProduct from PRODSET ps
         inner join cte on ps.Product= cte.SetProduct
         )

select distinct cte.SetProduct from cte
```

Adding "create view" gives error "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SET'" on the last line. I am not even using SET.

Whole code:

```
create view wiev_product as

with cte as (
         select ps.SetProduct from PRODSET ps
         left join PROD pr on pr.Product= ps.Product
         where ...

         union all

         select ps.SetProduct from PRODSET ps
         inner join cte on ps.Product= cte.SetProduct
         )

select distinct cte.SetProduct from cte
```

I am acessing MS SQL server trought an unspecified ERP system. Is it the ERP limitation, or is there something wrong with my query?

Is there any work-around in code, that i could try?

Thanks.

Edit: Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP1)
Error 156 without ; `as with`
Error 102 with ; between as ;with cte

Comment: `trought an unspecified ERP system` - does it allow any DDL at all?

Comment: No one can read your mind or see your screen. You said "accessing ... thru an unspecified ERP system." What EXACTLY does that mean? Can you create the view using SSMS? And post the complete sql statement that generates the error as well as the view creation statement (if that isn't the source of the error).  Lastly provide the COMPLETE error message - every bit of it.

Comment: IF that is your whole query it must be some sort of bug/limitation with your ERP. This code appears to be valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an ERP limitation. Instead of creating view from cte and than using that view in the second query as an condition, i managed to do it all in single query with two cte's.

```
with cte1 as (
         select ps.SetProduct from PRODSET ps
         left join PRODUCT pr on pr.Product= ps.Product
         where ...

         union all

         select ps.SetProduct from PRODSET ps
         inner join cte on ps.Product= cte.SetProduct
         ),

    cte2 as (
         select ps.SetProduct from PRODSET ps
         left join PRODUCT pr on pr.Product= ps.Product
         where ...

         union all

         select ps.SetProduct from PRODSET ps
         inner join cte on ps.Product= cte.SetProduct
         )

select distinct cte1.SetProduct from cte1
where cte1.SetProduct not in (select ... from cte2 where ...)
```